# Using Ruby and Capybara, is there a way to search parent elements (potentially multiple) for css?

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I've been using Ruby and Capybara for testing a web application. The current thing I'm trying to do is, while I'm within a window (and iterating through elements in the window), I clicked on a drop down menu item.  The list of items in this drop down are not within the window's div, but the top most layer of the page.

The only way I was able to get the dropdown list to click the item I want was basically to do:

page.find(:xpath, "..").find(:xpath, "..").find(:xpath, "..").find(:xpath, "..").find(:xpath, "..").find(*element I want*) to iterate up parents until I got to the level the menu was at.

There has to be a cleaner way of doing this, as this type of searching is messy.  Is anybody aware of a more simple way of going up to find elements?

Thank you in advance for any help the community can provide.

Comment: I suppose I'm more curious if there is just a native capybara method I can call, rather then making my own function to do what I need to.

Comment: If you could provide the relevant portion of the html, it would be easier to visualize your problem and give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at testing with [Konacha](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha) and the [Mocha testing framework](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) with [Chai](http://chaijs.com/).  It's built for testing javascript and makes traversing the dom really easy.